# mysql percentage 2 decimals places

Tags: mysql, rounding, truncate

With the following MYSQL code I am trying to round my percentages to 2 decimal places, I have tried truncate and round but when i add all percentages up from my output i'm not getting 100% getting numbers like 99.9%, 99.95% etc

Please see my updated full query to also show the counts of each type, the percentage without rounding and percentage with rounding:

```
select
bondtype,
count(distinct secid) AS Count,
concat(count(distinct secid)/(select count(distinct secid) from wca.bond)*100, '%') as Percentage,
concat(ROUND(count(distinct secid)/(select count(distinct secid) from wca.bond)*100, 2), '%') as Percentage_with_Rounding
from wca.bond
group by bondtype;
```

The following is the output I get:

[image]

Notice Percentage_with_Rounding for bondtype CS should be 0.05% and Not 0.04%, all other counts look correct after rounding but just this one which I find strange. Thanks in advance

Comment: That’s how numbers work. If you round and add you don’t get the same result as just adding.

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL and not Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

like this
select cast(round(((1*100.0)/9),2) as decimal(5,2))

select
secidtype,
ROUND(truncate(concat(count(distinct secid)/(select count(distinct secid) from securities)*100.0), 2)) as Percentage
from wca.bond
group by secidtype;

Answer (score 1):

You are not calculating percentage in a "balanced" manner, the values produced by this:

```
select secidtype, count(DISTINCT secid) from WCA.BOND group by secidtype
```

could be more or less than a count from a different table:

```
select count(distinct secid) from SECURITIES
```

You could have millions in one table, and just a few in the other, there simply is no guarantee that such a set of percentages will add to 100. Here is an example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE bond(
>    secid INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
>    , secidtype integer
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO bond(secid) 
> VALUES 
>   (1)
> , (2)
> , (3)
> , (4)
> , (5)
> , (6)
> , (7)
> , (8)
> , (9)
> , (10)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE securities(
>    secid INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO securities(secid)
> VALUES 
>   (1)
> , (2)
> , (3)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   coalesce(secidtype,1) secidtype
> , count(DISTINCT secid) num_of
> , (SELECT count(DISTINCT secid)  FROM securities) other_table
> , TRUNCATE (
>   CONCAT (
>    count(DISTINCT secid) / (
>     SELECT count(DISTINCT secid)
>     FROM securities
>     ) * 100
>    , '%'
>    )
>   , 2
>   ) AS Percentage
> FROM bond
> GROUP BY coalesce(secidtype,1);
> ```
>
> ```
> secidtype | num_of | other_table | Percentage
> --------: | -----: | ----------: | ---------:
>         1 |     10 |           3 |     333.33
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3dc0e17eede469884a5d5f267270c24)*

Comment: my apologies i made a mistake in my query and am actually using 1 table